# Eclipse JDT: Debugging in the same IDE instance

Tags: debugging, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, projects

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin that needs to specifically make use of Workspace, Projects, Packages, Compilation Units etc.

I already have a decent number of projects, packages, and compilation units in my workspace (not all related to my plugin though, but present nevertheless), which I would like to be able to use as a 'test dataset' for debugging.

When I click the toolbar icon of my plugin, I can print to the console the names of the projects returned by this statement:

```
IProject[] projects = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects();
```

However, when I launch the debugger, a new Eclipse IDE instance starts up with no projects visible in it anymore. While no project is visible, the `projects` array does list the project `RemoteSystemTempFiles`!

But this is completely useless for my debugging needs, as I need some good data set to step through during debugging.

**Question:**  Is there any way to make my projects existing in the development instance of the IDE appear in the second, debugging instance also? Or, if not, can I somehow debug in the same IDE instance instead of starting a second one? I would hate to litter all my code with console-log messages - it's very tedious also to write them in the first place. Setting up the existing test data in the plugin's initialization code would also be way too much work, which I would like to avoid as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't run or debug in the same instance. Eclipse will always start a new instance.

You will have to set up the test workspace to contain the data you need to test with.

Comment: I kinda feared that. Thanks. +1.